# Convert Dataframe with Vector column to Dataset - which type to be used in the case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe with a **column of vector type** as a result from onehot encoder. Let's name the column **Vector**.

With a **case class Example(vector: WhichType)**, I want to map the dataframe to a Dataset:

```
val ds = dataframe.as[Example]
```

Question is: Which type should the property 'vector' in the case class have.

I get an error message:

> need an array field but got structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Spark ML, then you can use the Vector type imported below:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

case class Example(vector: Vector)
```